# Jest Test Error for css

Tags: babeljs, jestjs

[image]

I am writing some test for my React components and been stuck on this error. How do i make jest pass this test?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules) on how to mock CSS modules. The main idea is to mock all `.css` imports with the [`identity-obj-proxy`](https://github.com/keyanzhang/identity-obj-proxy) by setting it in your jest settings like this:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```